# How to get a new object by filtering certain elements from an inner nested object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object by filtering an existing one. 
What I am trying to achieve is to filter the inner object `activities` and just get all the `completed_at` values that are below `1546964467`.

What I tried for now is this:

```
this.weekHabits = this.formattedHabits.filter(habit =>
    habit.activities.map((item) =>({
        activities: item.activities.completed_at.filter(
            value => value = 1546646400
        )
    }))
)
```

But is clearly wrong

thanks for your patience, any help will be immensely appreciated

this is the original object:

```
[
   {
      "frequency":[
         7,
         6,
         2,
         1
      ],
      "description":"Walk 100km",
      "color":"#E97825",
      "activities":[
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546646400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546819200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546905600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547251200
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547424000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547510400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547856000
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1548028800
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "frequency":[
         5,
         4,
         3,
         1
      ],
      "description":"Drink 4lt Water",
      "color":"#ED1E24",
      "activities":[
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546387200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546473600
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1546560000
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1546819200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546992000
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547078400
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547164800
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547424000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547596800
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547683200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547769600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1548028800
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "frequency":[
         7,
         6,
         5,
         4,
         3,
         2,
         1
      ],
      "description":"Study 2",
      "color":"#F4ED59",
      "activities":[
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1546387200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546473600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546560000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546646400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546819200
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1546905600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546992000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547078400
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547164800
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547251200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547424000
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547510400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547596800
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547683200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547769600
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547856000
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1548028800
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "frequency":[
         7,
         6,
         5,
         4
      ],
      "description":"Home drinking food2",
      "color":"#00A651",
      "activities":[
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546473600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546560000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546646400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547078400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547164800
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547251200
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547683200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547769600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547856000
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "frequency":[
         7,
         4,
         3,
         2,
         1
      ],
      "description":"New habit 4",
      "color":"#912AD6",
      "activities":[
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546387200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546473600
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546819200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1546905600
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1546992000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547078400
         },
         {
            "completed":false,
            "completed_at":1547424000
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547510400
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547596800
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1547683200
         },
         {
            "completed":true,
            "completed_at":1548028800
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: i think you want `value <= 1546646400` instead of `value = 1546646400`

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected output format?

Comment: i am so sorry i meant

`this.weekHabits = this.formattedHabits.filter(habit => 
    habit.activities.map((item) =>({
    activities: item.activities.completed_at.filter(value => value < = 
    1546646400)
    })))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed some stuff over there, you are trying to use the repsonse of a `map` as a filter condition, then the map that you are using should be a filter, basically the ivnerse of what you did.

I think this is what you wanted:

```js
this.formattedHabits = [{
    "frequency": [
      7,
      6,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "description": "Walk 100km",
    "color": "#E97825",
    "activities": [{
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546646400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546819200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546905600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547251200
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547424000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547510400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547856000
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1548028800
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "frequency": [
      5,
      4,
      3,
      1
    ],
    "description": "Drink 4lt Water",
    "color": "#ED1E24",
    "activities": [{
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546387200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546473600
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1546560000
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1546819200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546992000
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547078400
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547164800
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547424000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547596800
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547683200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547769600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1548028800
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "frequency": [
      7,
      6,
      5,
      4,
      3,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "description": "Study 2",
    "color": "#F4ED59",
    "activities": [{
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1546387200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546473600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546560000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546646400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546819200
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1546905600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546992000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547078400
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547164800
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547251200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547424000
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547510400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547596800
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547683200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547769600
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547856000
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1548028800
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "frequency": [
      7,
      6,
      5,
      4
    ],
    "description": "Home drinking food2",
    "color": "#00A651",
    "activities": [{
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546473600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546560000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546646400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547078400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547164800
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547251200
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547683200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547769600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547856000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "frequency": [
      7,
      4,
      3,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "description": "New habit 4",
    "color": "#912AD6",
    "activities": [{
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546387200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546473600
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546819200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1546905600
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1546992000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547078400
      },
      {
        "completed": false,
        "completed_at": 1547424000
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547510400
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547596800
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1547683200
      },
      {
        "completed": true,
        "completed_at": 1548028800
      }
    ]
  }
]

this.weekHabits = this.formattedHabits.map(habit =>
  habit.activities.filter(item => item.completed_at <= 1546964467)
)


console.log(this.weekHabits)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you missed in your code.

Comparison and assignment are not the same thing. This `value = 1546646400` should be `value <= 1546646400` in filter

```js
let obj = [{"frequency":[7,6,2,1],"description":"Walk 100km","color":"#E97825","activities":[{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546646400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546819200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546905600},{      "completed":true,"completed_at":1547251200},{          "completed":false,"completed_at":1547424000 },{            "completed":true,"completed_at":1547510400},{            "completed":true,"completed_at":1547856000},{            "completed":false,"completed_at":1548028800}]},{"frequency":[ 5,4,3,1],"description":"Drink 4lt Water","color":"#ED1E24", "activities":[{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546387200},"completed":true,"completed_at":1546473600},"completed":false,"completed_at":1546560000},{"completed":false, "completed_at":1546819200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546992000},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547078400 },{"completed":false, "completed_at":1547164800 },{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547424000},    {"completed":true,"completed_at":1547596800},"completed":false,"completed_at":1547683200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547769600},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1548028800}]},{"frequency":[7,6,5,4,3,2,1],"description":"Study 2","color":"#F4ED59","activities":[{"completed":false,"completed_at":1546387200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546473600},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546560000},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546646400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546819200},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1546905600},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546992000},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547078400},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547164800},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547251200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547424000},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547510400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547596800},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547683200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547769600},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547856000},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1548028800}]},{"frequency":[7,6,5,4],"description":"Home drinking food2","color":"#00A651","activities":[{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546473600},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546560000},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546646400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547078400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547164800},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547251200},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547683200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547769600},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547856000}]},{"frequency":[7,4,3,2,1],"description":"New habit 4","color":"#912AD6","activities":[{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546387200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546473600},
{
"completed":true,
"completed_at":1546819200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1546905600},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1546992000},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547078400},{"completed":false,"completed_at":1547424000},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547510400},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547596800},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1547683200},{"completed":true,"completed_at":1548028800}]}]

let op = obj.map(ele=>{
  let {activities} = ele
  let selected = activities.filter(element=> element.completed_at <= 1546646400 )
  return {
    ...ele,
    activities: selected
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe (looking at the code you implemented) that you want something like this, where we keep all the object structure, but we filter the `activities` array to keep only those elements that accomplish the condition `completed_at <= <some_number>`:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "frequency": [7, 6, 2, 1],
        "description": "Walk 100km",
        "color": "#E97825",
        "activities": [
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546646400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546819200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546905600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547251200},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547424000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547510400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547856000},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1548028800}
        ]
    },
    {
        "frequency": [5, 4, 3, 1],
        "description": "Drink 4lt Water",
        "color": "#ED1E24",
        "activities": [
             {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546387200},
             {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546473600},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1546560000},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1546819200},
             {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546992000},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547078400},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at":1547164800},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at":1547424000},
             {"completed": true, "completed_at":1547596800},
             {"completed": false, "completed_at":1547683200},
             {"completed": true, "completed_at":1547769600},
             {"completed": true, "completed_at":1548028800}
        ]
    },
    {
        "frequency": [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "description": "Study 2",
        "color": "#F4ED59",
        "activities": [
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1546387200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546473600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546560000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546646400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546819200},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1546905600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546992000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547078400},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547164800},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547251200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547424000},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547510400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547596800},
            {"completed": false,"completed_at": 1547683200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547769600},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547856000},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1548028800}
        ]
    },
    {
        "frequency": [7, 6, 5, 4],
        "description": "Home drinking food2",
        "color": "#00A651",
        "activities": [
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546473600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546560000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546646400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547078400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547164800},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547251200},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547683200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547769600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547856000}
        ]
    },
    {
        "frequency": [7, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "description": "New habit 4",
        "color": "#912AD6",
        "activities": [
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546387200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546473600},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546819200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1546905600},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1546992000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547078400},
            {"completed": false, "completed_at": 1547424000},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547510400},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547596800},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1547683200},
            {"completed": true, "completed_at": 1548028800}
        ]
    }
];

let res = input.map(x =>
{
    x.activities = x.activities.filter(
        ({completed_at}) => completed_at <= 1546646400
    );
    return x;
});

console.log(res);
```